Which Mosaic law was in the backdrop of ceremonial hand-washing in Mark 7?
We read of an interesting episode in Mark 7( CSB) , which starts thus:

The Pharisees and some of the scribes who had come from Jerusalem gathered around him.  They observed that some of his disciples were eating bread with unclean—that is, unwashed—hands. (For the Pharisees and all the Jews do not eat unless they give their hands a ceremonial washing, keeping the tradition of the elders.

We see Jesus unleashing a tirade against their hypocrisy, and insisting on the need for spiritual cleanliness.  Now,  in many tropical nations,  people rarely eat with spoon and fork, but rather use their fingers to break the tough flat  bread and to gather the side dish- either vegetarian or non- veg which too may have to be broken  into pieces ( say a roasted  whole chicken ) before consumption. Even among  rice- eating population, most find it convenient to eat with the help of fingers. For sheer reasons of  hygiene, and not from any religious viewpoint, they invariably wash their hands before eating. But in Mark 7, the Pharisees are speaking of tradition of the elders. That tradition may have come from a Mosaic law rather than direct from the science of hygiene , as is evident from the phrases like ' defiled'  and '  ceremonial washing'  ( Mk 7:2-3). My question is : which is the Mosaic law that may have contributed to the evolving of  ceremonial handwashing tradition of Jews ?

The most interesting part of this incident is that Jesus paid no regard to the tradition, whatever its origin. He just ignored it.

That is my point, Nigel J. Had it been for hygienic reasons, Jesus would have made a passing remarks like ' My disciples are immune to cough , cold and cholera ' rather than downplaying the tradition's importance from the perspective of physical hygiene. Let us remember that many Mosaic laws had physical hygiene in the backdrop, eg burning of clothes affected by mildew, abstaining from the meat of pork etc.

The "traditions of the elders" refers to the Oral Torah, rabbinical rulings that, according to Jewish understanding, continued to express God revelation on Sinai through the teaching of the rabbinical sages. Jesus referred to the authority of Oral Torah when he said
Mt 23:

2  “The scribes and the Pharisees have taken their seat on the chair
of Moses. 3 Therefore, do and observe all things whatsoever they tell
you...

In fact the written Torah does not require hand-washing for laypeople. It did require it for priests preparing to offer sacrifice:
Ex. 30

19 Aaron and his sons shall use it [the bronze basin] in washing their
hands and feet. 20 When they are about to enter the tent of meeting,
they must wash with water, lest they die. Likewise when they approach
the altar to minister, to offer an oblation to the Lord, 21 they must
wash their hands and feet, lest they die. This shall be a perpetual
statute for him and his descendants throughout their generations.

The Pharisaic ideal was to bring the practice of holiness to all Israel in daily life. Biblical support includes the teaching that only those with clean hands can approach God (Psalm 26:6) and the idea the God willed that Israel become a "kingdom of priests and a holy nation." (Exodus 19:6) In addition, washing one's hands provided a kind of insurance against various kinds of accidental impurity.  These ideals form the scriptural backdrop to the Pharisaic tradition of hand-washing.


The basis for handwashing in Judaism was originally related to the
Temple service and sacrifices, and it comes from the Torah in Exodus
17-21. [1]



Exodus 30:17-21 - Then the Lord spoke to Moses, saying: 18 “You shall also make a laver of bronze, with its base also of bronze, for washing. You shall put it between the tabernacle of meeting and the altar. And you shall put water in it, 19 for Aaron and his sons shall wash their hands and their feet in water from it. 20 When they go into the tabernacle of meeting, or when they come near the altar to minister, to burn an offering made by fire to the Lord, they shall wash with water, lest they die. 21 So they shall wash their hands and their feet, lest they die. And it shall be a statute forever to them—to him and his descendants throughout their generations.”

We see that God commands Moses to make a bronze basin for Aaron and his sons to wash their hands and feet before entering the Tent of Meeting or approaching the altar. This washing was to prevent them from dying! It was to be a lasting ordinance for Aaron and his descendants.
(ATS Bible Dictionary)

Various ceremonial washings were enjoined in the Mosaic law, both upon
priests, Exodus 30:19-21, and upon others, Le 12:1; 15:33 Hebrews
9:10.

Over time, the rabbis extended these practices to everyday life. This led to the tradition of hand-washing before meals, especially when bread was involved, as a way to maintain the sanctity of the Temple sacrifices in daily life.

After the destruction of the Temple, however, there was a change in
the focus of handwashing. Without the ritual objects and processes of
the sacrifices, and without sacrifices, the priests were no longer
able to wash their hands.
The rabbis, not wanting the handwashing ritual's importance to be
forgotten at the time of the rebuilding of the (Third) Temple moved
the sanctity of the Temple sacrifice to the dining room table, which
became the modern-day mizbeach, or altar.
With this change, the rabbis committed countless pages -- an entire
tractate -- of the Talmud to the halachot (laws) of handwashing.
Called Yadayim (hands), this tractate discusses the ritual of
handwashing, how it's practiced, what water is considered clean, and
so on. [1]


Handwashing does not show up in the Mosaic law with regards to meals, only for the priestly rituals.
However, in Deuteronomy Moses did create precedent for the law to be evolved. In the Deuteronomy scroll he evolved laws about worship (ex 20:20-26 vs deut 12:5-14), tithing (ch 14), cities of refuge (ch 19), divorce (ch 24), adding new laws about kingship (ch 17), and more.
Even Jesus seems to expect that the Jews would have reflected on the meaning behind the laws, thereby applying them more broadly, not just follow them:
Matthew 5:21-22 (NRSV):


“You have heard that it was said to those of ancient times, ‘You shall not murder’; and whoever murders shall be liable to judgment.

But I say to you that if you are angry with a brother or sister, you will be liable to judgment; and if you insult a brother or sister,
you will be liable to the council; and if you say, ‘You fool,’ you
will be liable to the hell of fire."



Matthew 5:27-28 (NRSV):


“You have heard that it was said, ‘You shall not commit adultery.’

But I say to you that everyone who looks at a woman with lust has already committed adultery with her in his heart."



However, Jesus' "tirade" as mentioned by the OP was for the pharisee's (religious leaders) failure to see the intent behind the laws, put them into practice, and be a people after God's own heart. Instead, they clung to a myriad of meaningless man made laws.
The idea of washing before meals may have been well intentioned, but again they missed the point. Priests were to do this as a part of temple ritual to avoid impurity when in the presence of God. It was a matter of life and death. Avoiding impurity at the dinner table doesn’t typically have the same stakes.
For reference, the Talmud, a compilation of rabbinic traditions and a comprehensive guide to Jewish (Mosaic) law, ethics, customs, and history and a primary source of law and theology.
There are many passages related to handwashing in the Talmud that suggest a lack of doing so renders the food or drink impure: Chullin 106a, Shabbat 62b, Sotah 4b. You can search these pages for references to eating, washing, meals, liquid, etc to see the discourse on the subject.
So the Mosaic law doesn't address handwashing, but it was centuries of expanding the law through rabbinic tradition, based on the Mosaic law, that lead to the encounter that Jesus rebukes.

There is no such Torah law or requirement; indeed, the text essentially says as much because it refers to this in Mark 7:3 as, "the tradition of the elders".  That is, not in the Torah!
Note that when something is a requirement of the Torah it is referred to as such or as "the law of Moses", or similar.
The closest we get to ceremonial washing in the Torah is:

Lev 15:11 - If the man with the discharge touches anyone without first rinsing his hands with water, the one who was touched must wash his clothes and bathe with water, and he will be unclean until evening.
Ex 30:17-21 - And the LORD said to Moses, “You are to make a bronze basin with a bronze stand for washing. Set it between the Tent of Meeting and the altar, and put water in it, with which Aaron and his sons are to wash their hands and feet. Whenever they enter the Tent of Meeting or approach the altar to minister by presenting an offering made by fire to the LORD, they must wash with water so that they will not die. Thus they are to wash their hands and feet so that they will not die; this shall be a permanent statute for Aaron and his descendants for the generations to come.”

However, neither of these applied to handwashing on every occasion before eating.  That is, the "tradition of the elders" greatly added to the rules found in the Torah.

The OP's translation may be causing difficulty.
This is Mark 7:3 - - Οἱ γὰρ Φαρισαῖοι καὶ πάντες οἱ Ἰουδαῖοι ἐὰν μὴ πυγμῇ νίψωνται τὰς χεῖρας οὐκ ἐσθίουσιν, κρατοῦντες τὴν παράδοσιν τῶν πρεσβυτέρων,
νίψωνται πυγμῇ doesn't mean ceremonial washing! Or even "careful" washing.
It just means they wash their hands. πυγμή is a fist - as in our word punch. It's an innate concept word - there are places where it might involve more or less of the forearm, but πυγμῇ νίψωνται τὰς χεῖρας looks pretty straightforward as idioms go. We don't say "I'm washing my hands with a punch" but back then and over there maybe they did.
We don't know and can't tell if it's like "careful" or "a quick swill"
Mark (or conceivably a very lucky scholiast of his) is explaining a cultural difference. His audience are far enough removed that they won't understand a hand-washing practice. He's clearly not talking about a ritually or religiously-legally required handwashing, or he wouldn't say Οἱ γὰρ Φαρισαῖοι καὶ πάντες οἱ Ἰουδαῖοι=The Pharisees and all the Jews... or παράδοσιν τῶν πρεσβυτέρων=the tradition of their fathers. So there's a contrast drawn between the priestly Pharisees and the ordinary Jews, and the word παράδοσιν is about to be placed in a contrast between the "laws" of God and the "traditions" of men (see v.7:8), which Matthew also has at 15:3 (when he's the apostle we'd least expect to contrast law and tradition)
This is of huge interest. It might show there is some cultural distance between Mark's audience and Jesus. And on this point moreso than from us - in the affluent, internet-using world we don't need this footnote to 'get' what handwashing is.
It must be it was of interest that in Jewish culture people only ate if they had first washed their hands. Why is this worth mentioning? Is it that an argument with the Pharisees is wanted at this point, and there's this rad aphorism Mark wants to 'thread on the necklace', about the laws of god and the traditions of men... and he just needs something for them to argue about. Which can't be the Torah (because Jesus is perfect on the Torah) but is still high-stakes stuff. This might not be any real tradition at all, it might be poetic license to set up for the aphorism. "You leave the commandment of God and hold to the tradition of men.”
But the translations embellishing this with 'ceremonial' might be more sinister. It could be it's trying to avoid us wondering why Mark is explaining something so obvious - by implying this is special and Pharisaic handwashing (contra the text). Bashing the Pharisees is always a W for commentators. But maybe there's a smidgen of antisemitism here. As if to say: those Jews, always with the ceremonial stuff - why can't they wash their hands normally like everyone else?
Looking at the MSS in case this is a daft scholiast's note that has been absorbed into the text, it turns out there is a textual variant πυκνὰ for πυγμῇ

This would then be "frequently" washing. Which might be closer to an idea of "carefully" but (i) it's a minority reading that the major translations have discounted (ii) it's probably a transposition error (iii) it's quite possibly that the scribe saw "washing the hands in a fist" and de-idiomized it.
This might be one to pass back to the papyrologists. Because it's got that banal, redundant character that scholiasts' notes often have. These days we can quite imagine ChatGPT spouting something like "People in Ancient Jewish culture regularly washed their hands in pursuit of hygiene and following traditions."

Thanks, FelixLXX. If you happen to watch Muslim brethren washing their hands before entering the Mosque to pray, you will be able to relate the issue. There is a laid down procedure. As for hygiene- oriented washing before eating,  all food centres in Southern India have washbasins with running water, so that their customers can wash their hands before and after eating. Luxurious hotels of course,supply tissue papers with food.
